# Select where all 3 columns are not null at the same time (Laravel Query Builder)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

There is `articles` DB table (and `Article` model) that has (among others) these 3 columns:

- `col_1`
- `col_2`
- `col_3`

How to select all of the articles where these 3 columns are **not** `NULL` **at the same time**?

So, if `col_1 = NULL` and `col_2 = NULL` and `col_3 = NULL` - do NOT select (include) those articles. But if one or more of these columns is NOT `NULL` - then select (include) it.

The query builder for this would look like this:

```
Article::select('articles.*')-> ... ->get();
```

Of course, instead of `...` there would be that check if all of these 3 columns are **not** null **at the same time**.

I know that this is wrong:

```
Article::select('articles.*')
       ->whereNotNull('col_1')
       ->whereNotNull('col_2')
       ->whereNotNull('col_3')
       ->get();
```

... because it will not select (include) the articles where, for example, one is NULL (`col_1`) and the rest (`col_2` and `col_3`) are not NULL.

**------------------ UPDATE: ------------------**

To clarify: I want to select (include) articles where **none or one or two** of `col_1`, `col_2`, and `col_3` is `NULL`, but **not if all three are** `NULL`.

Comment: To clarify, you *want* all articles which are not null across all 3 columns?    So if any of those 3 columns are not null, then that record should not be included?  If so, I believe the code you have should work.  Your last sentence is really throwing me off because it kind of contradicts what you previously said you wanted to happen.

Comment: @user3158900 If any of those 3 columns are not null, then that record should be included! It should not include only if all 3 are NULL.

Comment: Your query looks correct; chaining `->whereNoNull()` clauses will use `AND` logic, so your query is translating to `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE col_1 IS NOT NULL AND col_2 IS NOT NULL AND col_3 IS NOT NULL;`. Why doesn't this work? Can you compare the results from this query to running a raw query in your DB program (MySQLWorkBench, etc.)?

Comment: @TimLewis Hmmm, will this select (include) articles where, for example, `col_1` is **not** `NULL`, but `col_2` **is** `NULL`?

Comment: Nope; your query is saying only include articles where all 3 columns are not null. If any one of col_1, col_2 or col_3 is `null`, it won't be included. You need `whereNotNull()`, chained with 2 `orWhereNotNull()`... I think.

Comment: The requirement is not well explained, I think.  I think you want to select articles where one or two of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` can be `null`, but not all three - is that correct? What about where none are null?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've updated the question, but I'll answer here too: 
I want to select (include) articles where **none or one or two** of `col_1`, `col_2`, and `col_3` is `NULL`, but **not** if **all three** are `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query builder you are looking is :

```
$articles = Article::where(function($q){
   return $q->whereNotNull('col_1')
       ->orWhereNotNull('col_2')
       ->orWhereNotNull('col_3');
})->get();
```

The reason of adding the or clauses together in a closure is `to group them`. So if in future you would like to add another where like :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `articles`
WHERE 
    (`col_1` IS NOT NULL OR `col_2` IS NOT NULL OR `col_3` IS NOT NULL)
    AND
    `type` = 1
;
```

You an directly add :

```
$articles = Article::where(function($q){
   return $q->whereNotNull('col_1')
       ->orWhereNotNull('col_2')
       ->orWhereNotNull('col_3');
})
->where('type', 1)->get();
```

If you do this :

```
$articles = Article::orWhereNotNull('col_1') 
   ->orWhereNotNull('col_2')
   ->orWhereNotNull('col_3')
   ->where('type', 1)
   ->get();
```

It makes below query which is **not** what you will need :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `articles`
WHERE 
    `col_1` IS NOT NULL 
    OR `col_2` IS NOT NULL 
    OR `col_3` IS NOT NULL
    AND `type` = 1
;
```

Answer (score 4):

a simpler approach to do this is

```
Article::select('articles.*')
   ->whereNotNull(['col_1','col_2','col_3'])
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The query you are looking for would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `articles`
WHERE
    `col_1` IS NOT NULL
    OR `col_2` IS NOT NULL
    OR `col_3` IS NOT NULL
;
```

In Laravel this will result in the following:

```
Article::orWhereNotNull('col_1') 
   ->orWhereNotNull('col_2')
   ->orWhereNotNull('col_3')
   ->get();
```

The exact same select in `select('articles.*')` is done by Eloquent, if I am not mistaken. Maybe the first `orWhereNotNull` should be `whereNotNull` but also that you have to find out for your self.